# Windows Phone 8 upload and download file from https

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am developing windows phone 8 app. In this app I want to upload file to `https` server by using `HttpWebRequest`. How can I do it ? Is it possible to upload and download files from `https` server?

I tried this

```
    private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "https://url/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }
    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //TextBlockResults.Text = results; //-- on another thread!
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(results));
        }
        myResponse.Close();
    }
```

When I debug it show me like this:

[image]

And get exception `The remote server returned an error: NotFound.`

How can I **allow** `Https` request from my windows phone 8 app?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when the phone "does not trust" the server certificate. If you install the server certificate to the phone, it should work.

Save the certificate to your computer (see https://superuser.com/questions/97201/how-to-save-a-remote-server-ssl-certificate-locally-as-a-file). The upload it somewhere (Dropbox, SkyDrive, etc.) where you can get a public link for the file. The open the link in IE in the phone, you will be prompted to install the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can I install it?

Comment: How can I post json data in header?